# Should 'be' be put before "totally unaware" in this quote?

Tags: sentence-structure

This is from [a news article](https://newschannel9.com/sports/outdoors/snake-scare-copperhead-bites-chattanooga-preschooler-during-camping-trip-venom-snakes-reptiles) :

> Odds are, you will walk by one totally unseen and **totally unaware**
> that that snake was there,' Simms told us. 'However, because they are
> so well camouflaged, and they are not aggressive, they're not going to
> bother you if you don't bother them.

I think 'be' should be put before "**totally unaware**" here because 'unseen' is modifying 'one' and 'unaware' is describing the subject 'you'.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you will walk by one totally unseen and totally unaware that that snake was there

The real issue with this sentence is with "walk by one totally unseen", which is intended to mean that you won't see the snake, but actually means that the snake won't see you. Here is an example of correct usage:

> We had to crawl on our bellies, panic-stricken, in order to pass the guards unseen.  - *Yalta victim Zoe Polanska-Palmer 1986*

The second part, "and totally unaware" is correct because because you are the one that is totally unaware.

Comment: Thank you very much.